# mongodb - Prevent access to mongodb without authentication

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new for MEAN STACK web application. and I can not do proper authentication in mongodb.
I wants to prevent mongodb database access without user id and password.

dependencies
"mongodb"  => "version": "2.4.9",
"OS"  => "Ubuntu 14.04 lts 32bit",

Comment: Literally, the first google result for "Prevent access to mongodb without authentication" https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/

Answer (score 0):

Authentication is done in mongo database. Try this in mongo console to create user in database

```
use data_base_name
db.createUser(
{
user: "myUserAdmin",
pwd: "abc123",
roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
}
)
```

Now use the database url like this

```
mongodb://user:password@host:port/database_name
```

to connect to the database

Answer (score 0):

Plain and simple: You can not reliably. That's a bit like saying

> I want my house to be secure, but I do not want to use locks and keys.

To stay within the example, you *could* employ a doorkeeper (a firewall), but he could not reliably tell you apart from somebody who had a plastic surgery to look like you (IP spoofing, hijacked computer,...).

And this does not even cover authorization.

Imagine an apartment building where all the apartments do not have a door lock. Now, our doorkeeper lets you and all other people living in said building enter it. But since the doorkeeper is bound to it's place, everybody who could rightfully enter the building would be able to enter *any* apartment and steal things. Or drop forensic evidence in your flat, framing you for crimes you did not commit only to tell the police straight after that.

I think you get the picture: If your MongoDB instance is publicly accessible, add authentication and authorization. And even if you *think* it is not publicly accessible, it is better to make sure.